# iphone best practices for retrieving json data for a summary page

Tags: iphone, architecture

I have an architecture type question for you.  I'm creating a time entry iphone app.  I have one tab for entering data and another tab for showing summary data by week and by month.  I come from a web background, so my tendency is to make a request back to the server every time I need data.  Being new to iphone I'm not sure if it's a good idea to make a request for summary data every time the summary tab is clicked (via viewWillAppear).  The summary data is JSON, so it's fairly lightweight.  The summary data i not static, as it changes as the user enters data.  So, what are the best practices for when data should be retrieved?  Is there a better way to know when to retrieve data?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's a good idea. You should at least cache the data, so that the user may access the entries even if no network connection is available.

You might want to mirror your data structure into a core data model and update that by calling the server at appropriate times. If you're implementing the server side too, I'd model my request in a way that allows the server to send only those entries that have changed or have not been downloaded yet.

**Edit:**

To explain this further: Even if the data is lightweight, you're constantly producing traffic without a good reason. Some people have data plans that measure traffic by time, not by volume, they would literally pay for every second they're using your app...

Comment: Not to mention that when you're on a mobile data connection, latency can be the biggest cost so the fact that the packets being returned are small isn't actually much of a benefit. So, yeah, I agree with Toastor that at least a local cache is the best way forward.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  This gives me a lot to think about.

Comment: After thinking about this, would it be appropriate to save the "summary" JSON data results to a file, then rewrite the "summary" file whenever the data changes?  I could have an asynchronous call to fetch summary data whenever time is submitted.    This way clicking on the summary tab would load the contents of the "summary" file if it existed, otherwise it would fetch it and create the summary file.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with duplicating the data structure in core data model b/c i dont want data saved in multiple data stores (core data and my sql server db).  It seems saving the summary json results to a file would help alleviate round trips to server and eating up data plans etc.  thoughts?

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your data I can't really tell if using Core Data would give you an advantage over just saving and implementing code to handle "raw data", but the most important goal (from the perspective of a typical user) is to eliminate redundant traffic anyway - I guess you're free to choose the tools that you can handle best. Btw. don't think of Core Data as a form of database - it's more like a quite comfortable way to (locally) store structured data. It's at least worth a quick look at it if you haven't used it yet...

Answer (score 0):

Look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) framework if you haven't already. It supports queuing requests (with `NSOperationQueue` or `ASINetworkQueue`). You could queue some requests, and then call `[queue go]` for example in a `NSTimer` callback.

Implement your UI in a way that reflects when the network is active (network indicator) and update your UI elements asynchronously when new json data is available.

Also try using caches as *Toaster* suggests (Read about `ASIDownloadCache` etc.).